# File won't get uploaded by the formset

Tags: python, django

I have a form for my Lecture model and a formset which allows me to upload multiple files for every lecture. It used to work before but now my files won't get uploaded anymore.. I can't figure out what is wrong with it. My form has enctype and request.FILES is added to my view.. but files won't get saved no matter what.

```js
FileFormset = inlineformset_factory(Lecture, FileUpload, exclude=[])

class LectureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lecture_title = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True,
                                    widget=forms.TextInput(
                                        attrs={'class': 'lec_title', 'placeholder': 'Lecture Title'}))
    course = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'lec_course'}))
```

```css
 <form style="display: none" method="post" class="form2" action="{% url "classroom" %}"
                              enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <h5 style="text-align: center; margin-bottom:20px;">ADD LECTURE</h5>
                            {{ form1.course }}<br>
                            {{ form1.lecture_category }}<br>
                            {{ form1.lecture_title }}<br>
                            {{ form1.content }}<br>
                            {{ formset.management_form }}
                            {% for form in formset %}
                                <label id="file" for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
                                    <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i> File Upload
                                </label><br>
                                <span class="selected" id="file-selected"></span>
                                <input id="file-upload" name='files' type="file" style="display:none"/> <br>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <br>
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn2" type="submit">Add</button>
                        </form>
```

```html
 if 'form1-course' in request.POST:
            form1 = LectureForm(request.POST, user=request.user.teacher, prefix='form1')
            if form1.is_valid():
                lecture = form1.save()
                formset = FileFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=lecture, prefix='files')
                if formset.is_valid():
                    formset.save()
                    form1 = LectureForm(user=request.user.teacher, prefix='form1')
                    messages.success(request, 'Lecture added successfully.')
                formset.save()
        else:
            form1 = LectureForm(user=request.user.teacher, prefix='form1')
            formset = FileFormset()
```

Comment: Does the file actually reach the server or is it stuck in the browser? Have you tried debugging your code with your browser's console? Sometimes security warnings prevent the upload.

Comment: Yes I did using the ipdb. The file is in the memory but doesn't get to my folder.

Comment: 1) Would be better to check Path in Model again 2) Check Media configurations 3) Check Permissions to that folder, must be of 755

Comment: 1) path is alright 2) media is configured properly, every other model uplaod works 3) I don't really think is about that..